# Change format of a column in pandas with a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to give a specific format (enumeration with zeros) depending on the values of a pandas column.

So having the following column:

```
Name:
f_fb_sp_
f_fb_sp_
f_fb_sp_
f_fb_sp_
...
f_fb_sp_  (300 times)
f_fb_
f_fb_
f_fb_
...
f_fb_    (80 times)
```

I will need to create a new column with below format:

```
Index_Number:
001
002
003
...
300
01
02
03
...
80
```

So far I've made:

```py
df['Index_Number'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount()
df['Index_Number'] =df['Index_Number']+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `cumcount` is not hard , however,  you need to zero-fill

```
s=df.groupby('Name').cumcount()+1
df['Index_Number']=s.groupby(df['Name']).apply(lambda x : x.astype(str).str.rjust(width=len(str(max(x))),fillchar='0'))
```

---

Check

```
for x , y in df.groupby('Name'):
    print(y.head())

    Name Index_Number
0  f_fb_           01
1  f_fb_           02
2  f_fb_           03
3  f_fb_           04
4  f_fb_           05
        Name Index_Number
80  f_fb_sp_          001
81  f_fb_sp_          002
82  f_fb_sp_          003
83  f_fb_sp_          004
84  f_fb_sp_          005
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the builtin [`str.zfill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) (zero-fill) method and the `Series.str` accessor:

```
df['Index_Number'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1
df['Index_Number_str'] = (df.groupby('Name')['Index_Number']
                            .apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.zfill(len(str(max(x))))))
```